# Stacked or Grouped Barcharts from Weighted Survey Data (Class="survey.design2" "survey.design") in R

Tags: r, bar-chart, lattice, survey, contingency

I am working with weighted survey data of the class `survey.design2` and `survey.design`. With the package `survey`, and the function call `svytable`, I can create contingency tables for survey data. With these contingency tables, I can then create normal bar-charts using `lattice`. The standard way for doing this (e.g. `barchart(cars ~ mpg | factor(cyl), data=mtcars,...)`) doesn't work for this data type.

I am used to working with `ggplot2`, and would like to create either stacked or grouped bar-charts, if possible even with `facet-wraps`. Unfortunately, `ggplot2` does not know how to deal with data of the type `survey.design2` either. As far as I am concerned, there also does not exist some sort of add-on, which would allow `ggplot2` to deal with this kind of data.

So far I have:

1. sub-set my data set
2. converted it into class `survey.design2` with the function call `svydesign()`,
3. plotted multiple bar-charts in one window using `grid.arrange()`. This sort of provides for a work around for facetting, but still doesn't allow me to create stacked or grouped bar-charts.

I'd be grateful for any suggestions. 
Thank you

Comment: it would help to have a reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

Good morning MatthewR

I have a data set with 62732 observations and 691 variables. 
[Original Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLZUM.png)
So any example based on a random number generator should work as well, I guess. I am really just interested in a work around to this issue, not necessarily the final code.

I then convert the data frame into survey.design format using:
df_Survey <- svydesign(id=~1, weights=~IXPXHJ, data=df). IXPXHJ is the variable by which the original sample data set will be weighted so as to get the entire population. head(df$IXPXHJ) looks something like this:

87.70876
78.51809
91.95209
94.38899 
105.32005
56.30210

str(df_Survey) looks something like this.
[Survey Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRhf7.png)